# ORACLE - CHECK DATE TRIGGER

Tags: sql, oracle

Why this code doesn't work in ORACLE ?

```
CREATE TRIGGER chk_dates
BEFORE INSERT ON `job_history`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF (NEW.end_date < NEW.start_date) THEN
    SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'end_date cannot be earlier than start_date';
  END IF;
END;
```

I have a log:
ORA-00911:"invalid character"

Comment: Where in the [Oracle manual](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/toc.htm) did you find `signal sqlstate`? And why are you using a trigger for that? A simple check constraint will do. Also: `\`job_history\`` is an invalid identifier in SQL (and Oracle)

Answer (score 2):

You are mixing MySQL syntax with Oracle. There is no `SIGNAL SQLSTATE` in Oracle.

In Oracle, use `raise_application_error` to raise error.

```
BEGIN
  IF (:NEW.end_date < :NEW.start_date) THEN
    raise_application_error(-20001, 'end_date cannot be earlier than start_date');
  END IF;
END;
```

In this case, you don't even need a trigger as this can be easily achieved using a check constraint like this:

```
alter table your_table
add constraint contraint_name check (end_date >= start_date);
```